# Making IAB available to CORE module using libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, in-app-purchase

I was tasked with adding Google in app billing to an already existing project. After following the hoard of good and not-so-good examples out there, I have gotten it to communicate with Google on a basic level with IabHelper from within the android module. What would need to be done to be able to accomplish this from the core module?

Here is the main android code:

```
public abstract class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements IInAppBillingService{

// Debug tag, for logging
static final String TAG = "VL";

// SKUs for our products: the premium upgrade (non-consumable)
static final String SKU_PREMIUM = "CRED250";

// Does the user have the premium upgrade?
boolean mIsPremium = false;

// (arbitrary) request code for the purchase flow
static final int RC_REQUEST = 696969;

// The helper object
IabHelper mHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new VideoLottery(), config);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "123abcrinserepeat";
//It is recommended to add more security than just pasting it in your source code;
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
// Oh noes, there was a problem.
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
            }
// Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });


}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");
// does the user have the premium upgrade?
            mIsPremium = inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);

// update UI accordingly

            Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
            return;
        } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
// give user access to premium content and update the UI
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + ","
            + data);

// Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}

}
```

When run, the following is logged, so I *think* I'm on the right track...

```
 D/VL﹕ Query inventory finished.
 D/VL﹕ Query inventory was successful.
 D/VL﹕ User is NOT PREMIUM
 D/VL﹕ Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.
```

Any advice on where to go from here is greatly appreciated!